# How to install Atom packages on Windows-7 behind a firewall

Tags: proxy, atom-editor

I was trying to install Atom packages but was blocked, I got the following error:

```
"tunneling socket could not be established statuscode=407"
```

Answer (score 1):

After some trial and error, I see that when I add the following into the .apmrc file at `c:\users\<user_name>\.atom\.apmrc`, I am able to tunnel through the proxy.

```
proxy = https://<user-name>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<port>
https-proxy = https://<user-name>:<password>@<proxy-host>:<port>
```

However, after I close and launch Atom again, the entries are gone but Atom is able to tunnel through the proxy and show me the packages I want.

Any clues as to why the entries disappeared and how Atom is working?

Comment: `apm config set https-proxy https://9.0.2.1:0` ... from [github docs](https://github.com/atom/apm/#using-a-proxy)